# Output from this array

Tags: php

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(4) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["name"]=>
    string(3) "Lim"
    ["subproject_id"]=>
    string(1) "5"
    ["subproject_name"]=>
    string(4) "Mads"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(4) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(1) "1"
      ["name"]=>
      string(3) "Lim"
      ["subproject_id"]=>
      string(1) "4"
      ["subproject_name"]=>
      string(5) "KANYE"
    }
  }
}
```

How can I output each `name` and `subproject_name`?

A simple `foreach()` will only get the first one.

Comment: Seems incomplete. Additional `foreach` works, so I assume you're doing it wrong. You should show some code.

Comment: foreach inside foreach will help

Comment: There seems to be a mismatch in your array, the first entry has an array of id, name, etc within it but the second one has another level of array in it before hitting the array of id, name, etx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
array_walk_recursive($array, function($item, $key) {
    if (in_array($key, array('name', 'subproject_name'))) {
        echo $item;
    }
});
```

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php

Note: for PHP 5.3.0 you can use [callback](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php), in earlier versions you need non-anonymous function.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know how much that array could vary, but here is one simple solution.

```
foreach($array as $key => $value){

    if(!isset($value['id']))
        $value = $value[0];


    echo $value['name'];
    echo $value['subproject_name'];
}
```

if its getting deeper, you can use 'while' instead of 'if'.

Answer (score 0):

Consult the php documentation, look for "array_walk" and "array_walk_recursive".